# Highlight Specific Dates in Bootstrap3 Datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to highlight specific dates in an array in Bootstrap's Datepicker and am unable to make it work.  I would like to have something like the code below and can't find any examples.  Does anyone know how to make this work?

```
var dateValues = ['1/01/2015', '1/14/2015', '1/19/2015']

$('#events-calendar').datepicker({
highlightDates = dateValues 
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to add the feature myself, couldn't figure out any other way to do it.

The array looks something like this:

```
        [
            { "Class": "fault", "Date": "1995-06-23" },
            { "Class": "fault", "Date": "2014-05-01" },
            { "Class": "fault", "Date": "2015-06-17" },
            { "Class": "fault", "Date": "2015-06-14" }
        ]
```

Added the following to my options.

```js
  var options = {
                    highlights: allBindings.datetimepicker.attr.highlights || []
                };
```

Inserted the following code inside bootstrap-datetimepicker.js in the while loop of the 'fillDate' function:

```
        var cssClass = "";
            try {
                for (var j = 0; j < options.highlights.length; j++) {
                    var current = options.highlights[j];
                    if (current.Date == prevMonth._d.yyyymmdd()) {
                        cssClass = "faulted";
                        break;
                    } else {
                        cssClass = "";
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Date pick date highlighter" ' + e);
            }
```

And then I changed the following line:

```
     row.append('<td class="day' + clsName + '">' + prevMonth.date() + '</td>');
```

to:

```
     row.append('<td class="day' + clsName + ' ' + cssClass + '">' + prevMonth.date() + '</td>');
```

You can modify your 'faulted' class to any color you want. But mine looks like this:

```
.faulted {
background-color: red !important;
```

}

Out put looks like this:
[image]